# Activate screen buttons on the CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, buttons

I have a Xiaomi Mi3 running an Android 6.0 Cyanogenmod version and the back button doesn't work anymore.

In which way can I implement the standard touch buttons on the screen (home, back and menu) in order to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/system/build.prop` and add the line `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0`. Save and reboot. Should you want to revert, change that "0" to "1".

Alternatively, use a non-native solution such as [LMT Launcher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150).